# How to send json, after async function complete

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm using expressjs.
I have a router:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

  if(req.param('name')) {

    var simpleParser = require('../tools/simpleParser');
    var result = simpleParser.images(req.param('name'));

    // how i can get result from simpleParser.images after it complete?

    res.json(result);

  }

  res.render('goods');

};
```

An i have a simpleParser.images:

```
module.exports = {
    images: function (url) {
        if (url) {

            var request = require('request'),
                cheerio = require('cheerio');

            request({
                uri: url,
                method: 'GET',
                encoding: 'binary'
            }, function (err, res, body) {

                var tmp = [];

                body = new Buffer(body, 'binary');

                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                $('.products-listing li a').each(function () {
                    var link = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
                    tmp.push(link);
                });

                // How i can send tmp to router, when it complete?

            });

        }
    }
};
```

When i asking page with ?name it return null, because request in simpleParser.images work async. How i can subscribe to result of simpleParser request function, and send json after it complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many node modules, you can provide a callback in your own utility functions. Your `simpleParser.images` function is not synchronous, as it uses the `request` module. You can have your `simpleParser.images` function accept a callback that will be called upon the completion of the network request and some data parsing.

```
var request = require('request'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio');

module.exports = {
  images: function (url, callback) {
    if (!url) callback(null, null);

    request({
      uri: url,
      method: 'GET',
      encoding: 'binary'
    }, function (err, res, body) {
      if (err) callback(err);
      var tmp = [];
      body = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      $('.products-listing li a').each(function () {
        var link = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        tmp.push(link);
      });

      // Here we have the data and can pass it in the callback
      callback(null, tmp);
    });
  }
};
```

Then you essentially have your own function that can be performed asynchronously. Then in your 
express route, that is async as well, so just plug in your new function

```
if (req.param('name'))
  simpleParser.images(req.param('name'), function (err, images);
    res.json(images);
  });
} else {
  res.render('goods');
}
```